# bedtools coverage - Report the depth at each position in each A feature

Tags: sequence-alignment, bedtools, coverage

I am using bedtools coverage to compute the sequencing depth at every positions of a chromosome but it didn't work as I expected.
Instead it reported 0 coverage at every positions.

This is how I did it :

I made a `chr1.bed` bedfile :

```
chr start   end 
1   1   158534110
```

I ran this command  :

```
coverageBed -a -d chr1.bed -b aln.bam -s > coverage.perposition_chr1.tsv
```

However I don't find any position in the output that is actually covered :

```
chr start end 1-pos depth
1   1   158534110   1   0
1   1   158534110   2   0
1   1   158534110   3   0
1   1   158534110   4   0
1   1   158534110   5   0
1   1   158534110   6   0
1   1   158534110   7   0
1   1   158534110   8   0
(...)
1   1   158534110   158534109   0
```

I must do something wrong because I already computed depth at specific pattern positions using the same `aln.bam` and it was working fine...

**Suggestions and tries :**

- Swapping `-a` & `-d` parameters produces the same results
- Adding a strand column to the bedfile still gives 0 coverage.

`chr1.bed`

```
1       1       158534110       .       0       +
1       1       158534110       .       0       -
```

`output`

````
1       1       158534110       .       0       +       1       0
1       1       158534110       .       0       +       2       0
(...)
1       1       158534110       .       0       -       158534108       0
1       1       158534110       .       0       -       158534109       0
```
````

Comment: In your .bam file (and the original reference you used) are the chromosomes called '1' '2'; etc, or 'Chr1', 'Chr2' etc?  Also, you could try swapping the -a and -d - maybe the -a needs to be immediately before the .bed file.

Comment: @JonathanMoore I bet you're right. The `-a` expects a string, so that would take `-d` as the value for `-a`. Probably worth an answer already.

Comment: @JonathanMoore Yes this is the right chromosome name. I tried swipping parameters and it did produce the same file. @terdon wouldn't I expect an error If it indeed took `-d` as the `-a` value ? It is not fitting the right format

Comment: Consider posting 1-2 alignments in `sam` format, which you would expect to give non-zero coverage as the minimum reproducible example. What is the bedtools version? What happens if you drop `-s`?

Comment: @TimurShtatland Dammit that was it, the bam went blank at some point in my testing. I should have suspected that. It works now. My bad and thanks all for the suggestions..

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to have a more concise report than a per-base one, [bedtools genomecov](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/genomecov.html) could be a better choice.

Its `-bga` option allows you to report consecutive bases that have the same coverage as a range in a single line.

In your case, you could achieve this (unfortunately they only offer the strandedness option for a specified strand) by running the following command:

```
bedtools genomecov -bga -ibam aln.bam -g chr1.bed -strand + > coverage.perposition_chr1.tsv
```

Output will look like:

```
chr1  554304  554309  5
chr1  554309  554313  6
chr1  554313  554314  1
chr1  554315  554316  6
chr1  554316  554317  5
```